# Overfitting after feature engineering, data leakage?

Tags: r, cross-validation, overfitting, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with 2 continuous variables : cont and y (the target).
I found that y_train, when ordered by cont, is auto-correlated so I would like to create a feature using this property. I use a KNN regression with k = 100 here to create this new feature with the goal of capturing the underlying trend.

The problem I have is that the added feature yield overfitting. While traing an xgboost using cross-validation with the same folds as line 1 below, the training error is better but the testing error is worse (compared with training without the new feature).

It seems like there is data leakage but I paid attention to not leak information while creating the feature since I trained on var[-fold], y_train[-fold] and built the prediction from var[fold], for each fold.

Have you any idea why it's overfitting ?

```
library(FNN) # For the knn regression
library(caret) # For the createFolds
library(xgboost)

folds <- createFolds(y_train, k = 5)

predictions <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(y))
for(fold in folds) {
    knnReg <- knn.reg(train = train$cont[-fold], 
                      y = y[-fold], 
                      test = matrix(train$cont[fold]), 
                      k = 100)
    predictions[fold] <- knnReg$pred
} 
train$cont_knn <- predictions

xgb.cv(folds = folds, ...) # I train on the same folds used before to avoid data leakage.
                           # I obviously train on train and y
```

Comment: You can't say whether there is data leakage unless you _know what the data means_.